# Make style inline using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet, inline, styling

Im experimenting with setting up a automatic way of converting clean stylesheet based designs to ugly inline styled design (for a newsletter editor).

Is it possible to get all the styles that applies to an element (div, p, span, h1, h2 etc.) and apply them to that element as inline?

So instead of having my style nice and beautiful like this in a stylesheet:

```
#topHeader { color: #222; background: red; width: 210px; height: 110px;}
```

Having it be inline like this:

```
<div id="topHeader" style="color: #222; background: red; width: 210px; height: 110px;">
```

If anyone knows if this is at all possible, please send me in the right direction if you can.

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be interesting to you:

- IE: [currentStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Others: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do this using the `.style` member of the DOM element you're referencing.  Using your example, maybe something along these lines (untested):

```
var el     = document.getElementById('topHeader');
var styles = new Array();

for (var key in el.style) {
    // You'll probably need to do some more conditional work here...
    if (el.style[key]) {
        styles.push(key + ': ' + el.style[key]);
    }
}

el.setAttribute('style', styles.join('; '));
```

Comment: Interesting.. will try it out later today. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the document's styleSheets and rules:

```
$.each(document.styleSheets, function() {
    $.each(this.cssRules || this.rules, function() {
        var style = {};
        var styles = this.cssText.split(/;\s*/g);
        $.each(styles, function() {
            var parts = styles.split(/\:\s*/g);
            style[parts[0]] = parts[1];
        });
        $(this.selectorText).css(style);
    });
});
```

Not all browsers expose `.selectorText`, and `.cssText` will require browser-specific parsing.  Hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following with moderate success:

```
$('#parentidhere').find('*').each(function (i, elem){elem.style.cssText=document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem,"").cssText;});
```

Certain styling like background selectors for more complex styling still seem to vanish though, I haven't been able to figure out why yet.
Also this won't work in older browsers, but in my case that doesn't matter.